# Logic using the difference between two integer variables

Tags: python

I have a game that goes through rounds, which have the variables, `count1` and `count2` as score. I am trying to create some logic that plays the while loop till someone reaches 9, but also has to be 2 points ahead.

I feel like I'm getting close. I'm pretty sure the first portion's right. I keep trying to change the Boolean and format to see if I can get it to work.

```
while (count1 <= 9 and count2 <= 9) and ((count1 - count2 > 2) or (count2 - count1 > 2)):
```

Happy Path: The `while` loop loops through till someone gets to 9 and has a 2 point lead.

As far as errors go, it keeps going to end game since that is the else statement, which tells me that my logic is still a bit off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are keeping the loop running if one is ahead by 2 points while I believe you want the opposite:

```
while (count1 <= 9 and count2 <= 9) and ((count1 - count2 > 2) or (count2 - count1 > 2)):
```

I haven't seen the rest of your code, but this should probably work:

```
while (count1 < 9 and count2 < 9) or abs(count1 - count2) < 2:
```

Comment: you got the point: stop when count >=9 and the diff is more than 2. So continue which opposite. So let write it as: !( (count1 >=9 or count2>=9) and (abs(count1 - count2) > 2)). after remove the ! you get the answer above

Comment: @NamNguyễn Correct, you can achieve the same result by coming from the opposite end. This is called De Morgan's transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's deal with it bit-by-bit:

You want the loop keep running. When someone hit 9 points or more, and score difference is 2 or more, stop the loop.

Easiest translation will be:

```
# s1 and s2 representing score 1 and 2
while True:
    if (s1 >= 9 or s2 >= 9) and abs(s1 - s2) >= 2:
        break
    # do something
```

Which also implies, when the condition is NOT met, we keep going:

```
# s1 and s2 representing score 1 and 2
while not ((s1 >= 9 or s2 >= 9) and abs(s1 - s2) >= 2):
    # do something
```

Some basic boolean arithmetic simplify the condition:

```
# s1 and s2 representing score 1 and 2
while (s1 < 9 and s2 < 9) or abs(s1 - s2) < 2:
    # do something
```

For which the condition also reads correct: we keep looping while both scores are under 9, or (at least one reaches 9 and) score difference is less than 2.

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed explanation, but I am confused by your first sentence. How is my answer not giving the correct behaviour when your final simplified expression is exactly the same?

Comment: Oh my fault! I mistakenly read your first line of code as answer.  I will update my answer to remove that comment